# A Hypothetical Quantifier in Predicate Logic

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

[image]

[image]

My answer for this question is...

S=<{e1,e2,e3,...e10},I}
I(linguist)={e1,e2,e3,...e10}
I(married)={e1, e2,... e7}

I meant that there are 10 people, and 7 people out of 10 are linguists.To do this, I wanted to prove that "less than 60% of linguists are married". And, I wanted to prove that " Qx(linguist(x)∧married(x)) " is true.

Comment: For A you have to apply the "semantical specifications" provided, taking into account that "less than 60%" for a domain of 10 elements means not more than 5.

Comment: Thank you for replying to me :) Could you please give me more detailed explanation about "semantical specifications"?

Comment: They are the rules for the interpretation of the quantifier $Qx$ and of the predicate *linguistic* and *married* : if $D = \{ e_1, \ldots, e_{10} \}$, then both $I(linguistic)$ and $I(married)$ must be subsets of $D$. In order to satisfy or falsify the formulas, as requested, you have "to play" with the numbers of elements of them.

Comment: Thank you, Mauro. I'm thinking what I can put the inside the bracket... Maybe something like, I(linguist)={more than 60% of linguists married } or {exactly 50 % of linguists married} ? I am sorry if I'm not on the completely wrong track..

Comment: NO; if they must be (suitable) subsets of $D$, you have to **list** the elements, like $I(linguist)= \{ e_1, e_2, e_3 \}$ and $I(married)= \{ e_1, e_2 \}$.

Comment: "10 people, and 7 people out of 10 are linguists." What you have written in the list is different: there are 10 elements (in $S$): all of them are linguists and 7 out of 10 are also married.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm confused now...  ;( My model was there are at least 7 people who are both linguists and married in the model. About the three people in the model, they are linguists but not married. In this way, (1a) can be false, and (1b) is can be true. Therefore, I thought I gave a correct model of this domain?

Comment: Ok; by **YOU** have written: "I meant that there are 10 people, and 7 people out of 10 are linguists."

Comment: (1a) Correct: if there are 10 linguists and 7 of them are married, then it is *false* that less than 60% of the linguists are married (because 7/10=70%).

Comment: (1b) Wrong: 7 are linguists **and** married: thus 7/10=70% of the total population is made of married linguists. Thus, it is *false* that less than 60% of the elements of $S$ (the "population") are married linguists.

Comment: Okay, I think I finally reach the answer (1a)? This question is asking me to give an example model. Do you think the answer is what I edited above? Now, I'm not sure how I should answer this question...

Answer (score 2):

(A) For the domain $S$ with 10 elements, we can use:

> $I(linguist) = \{ e_1,e_2,e_3 \}$ and $I(married) = \{ e_1,e_2 \}$.

In this way, we have that 2 on 3 linguists are married: $\dfrac 2 3 = 0.66$ and 66% > 60%.

Thus, (1a) is *false*.

At the same time, we have that only 2 elements of the domain $S$ are both linguists and married: $\dfrac 2 {10} = 0.2$ and 20% < 60%.

Thus, (1b) is *true*, because less than 60% of the elements of the domain $S$ are linguists and married.

---

(B) Now we want that (2a): "Less than 60% of the linguists are married" comes out *true*.

This is quite straightforward: it is enough to choose sets $I(linguist)$ and $I(married)$ in the ratio $2 : 1$.

But we want also that (2b): "$Qx \ (\text {linguist} (x) \to \text {married}
 (x))$ is *false*.

This means that we want that at least 60% of the entities in $S$ make the formula $\text {linguist} (x) \to \text {married} (x)$ *true*.

In conclusion, we can set: $I(linguist) = \{ e_1,e_2 \}$ and $I(married) = \{ e_1 \}$.

We have that 1 on 2 linguist is married: $\dfrac 1 2 = 0.5$ and 50% < 60%. Thus, (2a) is *true*.

At the same time, for every $e_i, i=3,\ldots,10$ we have that $\text {linguist} (e_i) \to \text {married} (e_i)$ is *true*.

Thus, 80% of the total population of $S$ satisfy the formula $\text {linguist} (x) \to \text {married} (x)$, and his means that "$Qx \ (\text {linguist} (x) \to \text {married} (x))$ is *false*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You are amazing! I am almost getting to understand this :) Now, based on your hint, I might have to make a similar model with 10 entities, right?

Comment: M=< {e1, e2,...., e10}> where: I(linguist)={e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10}, I(married)={e1, e2, e3, e4, e5} In this way, there are five linguists who are married. This is the same as "less than 60%" for a domain of 10 elements.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the number but I think I'm confused again. I'm sorry :(

Comment: @user444331 - sorry, corrected the misprint. The domain with 10 elements is $S$. It is fixed for both A and B; what we have to change for B are the subsets used for the interpretation of the predicates.

Comment: I edited my question and added my answer for the question. Could you pleas go through it? Would you be able to tell me if they are correct or still wrong?